# Framerate drop when looking at panels?

Tags: technical-issues, portal-2, ubuntu

I've recently installed Portal 2 on my Ubuntu partition, and I've noticed an interesting issue that has popped up while playing community test chambers, but it has also surfaced around the beginning of story mode Chapter 1. I can usually get upwards of 60-70 FPS based on my graphics settings, but whenever I look at a movable panel, my frame rate drops severely, usually to below 30 FPS. My specs are as follows:

> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
>
> Kernel version 3.18.0-031800-generic
>
> Intel Core i5-4200U (2 physical cores, 4 total logical cores)
>
> Intel HD Graphics 4400 iGPU (Driver: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller version 09)
>
> (Note: The driver version number is according to the output of `sudo lshw -C video`)

And my Portal 2 video settings are:

> Aspect ratio: 16:9
>
> Resolution: 1366 x 768 (Native)
>
> Display mode: Full screen
>
> Laptop power savings: Disabled
>
> Splitscreen direction: Default
>
> Anti-Aliasing: None
>
> Filtering mode: Trilinear
>
> Wait for Vertical Sync: Disabled
>
> Multicore Rendering: Enabled
>
> Shader Detail: Low
>
> Effect Detail: High
>
> Model/Texture Detail: Low

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? I'm still able to play normally, but the FPS drops catch me off-guard and can get annoying.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "movable panels"? Can you give us a better description of what's causing the issue please?

Comment: @Thom Have you played the game? Panels are used for walls, floors, ceilings and even crushers. Some panels can be moved/adjusted and due to the story line in some levels these panels move all the time, from technical view, they are making constant level & shader related updates. Now, why these updates are causing such big performance drop is the real question, and I would guess it's driver related.

Comment: Yeah, I know what he means by movable panels now.